# Pip error: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, python-3.6

I've seen many threads about this, and have tried all options except for completely wiping Python off of my machine and re-downloading everything...

I'm using a Windows 10, 64-bit machine, and had already downloaded Python2.7. Commands like 'C:\>pip install seaborn' were not an issue.

I recently downloaded Python3.6, and now my pip will not work - it returns the error in the title.

I have added `C:\Python27, C:\Python36, C:\Python27\Scripts, C:\Python36\Scripts` to my Path, and still it won't work.

If I type in the command `C:\>python27 -m pip install seaborn`, however, the pip works. I am really confused why I can no longer just type in pip install  and have it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have two versions of Python added to path.  To differentiate between 2.7 and 3.6 you have to tell it which version you want otherwise each pip conflicts with the other (it does not know what to install and where) in other words you type `pip` you could either mean for Python 2 or for Python 3.

Do not rename `pip` it will break your system (you should not need to rename).  Instead use those [already provided.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions).

Your system should have these already:

`pip` is universal.  Best for one installation.

`pip3` for Python 3.  Best to distinguish between Python 2 and 3

`pip3.6` to distinguish between different Python 3 installations.

The same goes for Python 2 installation.

`pip`, `pip2` and `pip2.7`.

You need to use either `pip3` (or `pip2`) or `pip3.6` (or `pip2.7`) to install in future.  This will allow the different versions to be recognised:

For Python 2:

```
pip2 install seaborn
```

For Python 3:

```
pip3 install seaborn
```

---

You should also now use shebang lines as well now (if you are not already) to distinguish between versions.

Comment: Why are you copying my answer mate? I am gonna flag it

Comment: @iam.Carrot  I am putting that back in.  You method involves renaming.  I think otherwise.  My solution is different to yours.

Comment: yeah now it's taken in a different direction. I'll retract the flag. Thanks for the effort on your part. I really appreciate it

Comment: @iam.Carrot  Sorry about that I was not copying (and I am pleased that that you told me that it looked similar otherwise I would not have changed it).  I am too vague often.  I am very sorry for the confusion I caused. :(

Answer (score 2):

the issue is the ambiguity between the two `pip` that you've mentioned in the `Environments`. As you mentioned the issue only started occurring when you installed `python3` on the same system where `python2` was installed and both have `pip` and hence when you fire up `pip` in your `cmd`, Windows System isn't able to pick one out of the two.

**Why does your `C:>python27 -m pip install seaborn` work?**
Well it's quite simple, since you've mentioned the `python27` there, windows knows exactly which pip you're talking about.

---

---

### How to fix it?

> see the edits for this section. (I tried this, it didn't work) Removed it from the final answer to avoid confusion.

---

Alternatively, what you can do is,

rename your python.exe for python 3 to python3. Don't forget to put it inside your PATH environment. Just use python for python 2, python3 for python 3.
Their pip are separated, pip for python 2. pip3 for python 3.

Now, run and see the below commands behave:

```
# will return the default version of pip
pip --version
# will use the Python 2 version of pip
pip2 --version
# will use the Python 3 version of pip
pip3 --version
```

Comment: I tried that as well. I renamed each pip.exe as pip27 and pip36, respectively. When I enter 'C:\pip27 install <whatever>', I still get the original error.

Comment: @AtlasKing did you restart your `cmd` after changing the environment settings and the file names?

Comment: @iam.Carrot I closed out of the window, yes. Additional info - I have 3 different pip files for both Python2 and Python 3. They are as follows:
pip
pip2
pip2.7

Python3 has similar names for its pip files.

Why are there 3? I didn't download/delete anything that the default Python download incurred...Could there be a problem there?

Comment: @AtlasKing I've updated the answer can you please try now?

Comment: @Simon I think I may have goofed up...I tried renaming my original 'pip', the universal .exe :(

even now when I call pip, pip2, or pip3, it still gives me the original error. Should I uninstall Python3 and redownload?

Comment: @AtlasKing  Have you renamed everything to what is was before.  Once you have run `pip3` and it should work.

Comment: @AtlasKing If it still does not work remove one of them from path (2.7) and just test `pip` see if the error goes if it does not you might have to. If it does add it back to path and try what I suggested below.

Comment: @Simon I renamed everything to its original/default setting. Still no luck.

I also tried removing everything but Python27 and Python27\Scripts from my Path. Also no luck...

Comment: @AtlasKing uninstall `python 3` try the `pip` if it works then great. re-install `python 3` in a different directory. Set the environment variables and then fire the 3 commands that I've mentioned `pip --version`, ``pip2 --version` and `pip3 --version` in your cmd

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I finally worked it out...

I uninstalled Python3.6 and deleted all relevant folders.

I then went to Control Panel>Programs>Progams and Features and repaired my Python2.7 program. pip works now (I think it got messed up since I tried to rename the universal pip.exe file -> don't do that!!).

After re-downloading Python3.6, I put my universal pip.exe download from Python3 in a different directory so the Path would not get it confused. I now have Paths for both pip2 and pip3 and all is okay.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue on my end: (short answer, remove this folder C:\Python27)

**Problem**: I installed python 3, after uninstalling python 2.7. The issue here is that pip remains behind even after you uninstall python 2.7.

**Solution**:
1. Uninstall python 3 (if you have it installed).
2. Just in case, I would uninstall python 2.7.
3. This is the key: go to C:\Python27 ... and delete the entire directory (which also contains pip).

This solution is good for those that are fine with ONLY running Python 3 on their machines (which was my case).